# Storyboards and init, or how to pass parameter during initialization?

Tags: swift, swift2

When using storyboards, the system creates the corresponding `ViewVontroller`.  Without storyboards, I can express the `ViewController` as a function of the database e.g. `ViewController(database:Database)`, e.g. by using init, and binding the database to the database property of the `ViewController`.
Using storyboards however, I seem to have no control over the view controllers initialization (using the instantiation methods).  While I can obtain the viewcontroller and set properties after the construction, these properties are by nature `Optional`.  Hence viewing the `ViewController` as a function of the database is not possible.

Is it possible to use the `ViewController` as a function of a supplied database, together with storyboards?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I usually did in that case is declaring database as explicity unwrapped:

```
var database: Database!
```

And in `viewDidLoad` I leave assertion to make sure database is set:

```
 assert(nil != database, "\(self.dynamicType) must have database initialized inside viewDidLoad")
```

It's not so classy as passing in `init`, but does pretty much the same job.

Comment: This is a pretty good work around. I'll go with this for now.

Answer (score -2):

Make your database a lazy var. That way it won't be an optional, but it will get initialized the first time it's referenced.

```
lazy var database: Database = {
    let db: = Database()

        // do what you need to initialize it

    return db 
}()
```

Comment: This sidesteps the question. You are lazily building the database, but not passing it on. This way your ViewController is not a function of the database, but initializes the database on demand.  The crucial part is that the database *must* exist initialized, prior to showing the ViewController.